# How to count the number of repetition of different values in Excel?

Tags: excel, count

I have data set which is for example like this:

```
axz 
www 
www 
axz 
hhh 
mjk 
www
```

And I want to get something like this:

```
axz 2
www 3
www 3
axz 2
hhh 1
mjk 1
www 3
```

I know to get that with countif function, but only for a few specific values. Now I have much more values, so It's not practical for me to use countif where I suppose to know every value which occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say "It's not practical for me to use countif where I suppose to know every value which occurs". But you can also use a cell as criterion.

Assuming that your column A contains the values axz,www,... you could use the formula below to get your count:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)
```

... and then just "pull" the cell down, which will update the criterion automatically.

[image]

Comment: But I have about 3000 different values, so its 3000 cell selection criterion.

Comment: @Neven No matter 3000. Just put formula in a cell and drop and down.

Comment: Yes, 3000 is not a problem for Excel :) You don't need to manually update to criterion. You can just write the first one, double click on the bottom right of the cell (the small square of the highlighted cell) and Excel will do the rest.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. Thank you :)